# Boostrap table button don't work after search

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I have a problem with the component "Bootstrap table". I have a column that show a simple popover when clicked, but if I change page or search a result, if I re-clicked it, doesn't show anymore the popover (this problem happened not only with popover , but also with other js method). Even if I used DataTable, this problem doesn't happen. How can I fix it? That's my code:

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.min.css">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Jquery library for bootstrap-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<table class="table color-table info-table" data-toggle="table" data-search="true" data-classes="table-no-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="codice" data-sortable="true">Codice</th>
      <th data-field="nome" data-sortable="true">Nome</th>
      <th data-field="server" data-sortable="true">Server</th>
      <th data-field="database" data-sortable="true">Database</th>
      <th data-field="versione" data-sortable="true">Versione</th>
      <th data-field="attivo" data-sortable="true">Attivo</th>
      <th>Licenza</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="txt-oflo">17894</td>
      <td>Ekipe</td>
      <td class="txt-oflo">oasis.amcweb.it</td>
      <td>ET_017894</td>
      <td>5.16.20</td>
      <td>SI</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="popover" title="TEST 2" data-content="Some content inside the popover" data-placement="top">Visualizza</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="txt-oflo">14785</td>
      <td>Ekipe</td>
      <td class="txt-oflo">web.amclab.it</td>
      <td>ET_017894</td>
      <td>5.16.20</td>
      <td>SI</td>
       <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="popover" title="TEST 1" data-content="Some content inside the popover" data-placement="top">Visualizza</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: When you sort, the html elements/nodes are removed from the DOM and re-added.  At that point, any events assigned to them no longer work as events only work on DOM elements that exist at the time the event is initiated.   You should be able to get around this by re-initiating the popover after the sort (ie hook into the sort event and call `$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();` )

Comment: fix it -->    <script src="//cdnjs......

Comment: @freedomn-m that's a problem, now I have a simple popover, but in the future, if I have more component in my table, I can't anytime re-initiating them. At this point, is better use DataTable, even if Bootstrap Table is more sample to use for determinate things

Comment: Most of the time you wont need to re-initiate if you use delegated events (eg click handlers).   However, I don't see why you "can't anytime re-initiate" - simply put your init script in a separate function and call it from both doc ready and sort.  That way you only have one set of init code, but call it from both places.  So it doesn't matter how much code is there as you're maintaining it for initial init anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should run execute `$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();` everytime after you trigger the script modifying the table.

**Update 1:**

This would be easier, replace the existing script with this:

```
$('table').on('post-body.bs.table', function () { $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); });
```

Don't forget to replace $('table') with your specific table you intend for it to take effect.

Comment: I don't like this solution, at this point it's better use DataTable, that doesn't have this problem

Comment: I'm afraid you may have no other choice here, except in Update 1.